# how to destroy a specific object when touch it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hey guys I am trying to destroy a specific object coming towards me when touch it just like guitar hero.

my code right now just destroy wherever I touch

I am new to coding so I appreciate a basic explanations thx you

```
{
 private float forcemult = 200;
   
 private Rigidbody rb;
   
 Ray  ray;
   
 RaycastHit hit;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forcemult * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        }

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out  hit ))
        {
            Debug.Log("hit something");
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean like checking the `Input.GetTouch(0).position` and if it is not within a certain range ignore the tap? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can give your gameobject a specific tag and then check if the gameobject you hitted has this tag.

Something like:

```
if(hit.collider.tag == "Enemy") {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

This is the simplest way to check for a collision with a specific gameobject.

You can also check if the name of the gameobject you hitted has the name you want for example:

```
if(hit.collider.gameobject.name == "Enemy01") {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I personally don't like the name checking variant, because it only works reliably in specific situations.

Another method you can use is attaching a script to the gameobject and then check if the gameobject has this script:

```
YourScript script = hit.collider.gameobject.GetComponent<YourScript>();
if(script != null) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This is probably the best way of handling this because you can instantly call an event after the collision happened.

Comment: thx for answered  but i cant make it work i dont know why                                                                                                                                              
         Debug.Log  ("hit rb");
            Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>); // the Error it said cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Object'
            {
                if (rb != null)
                {
                    Destroy(rb);
                }
            }

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your exact problem

Comment: when i try the  YourScript script coding there comes a Error it said cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Object'

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code that is responisble for detecting objects is  `if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out  hit ))`. You can add two additional inputs to this method to destory the objects you desire. The first input is `maxDistance` which is the max distance the ray should check for collisions, the second one is `layerMask` which is a Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore colliders when casting a ray.

Define a new layer in unity and assign it to the objects you wish to desotry.

[image]

click on edit layers:

[image]

Define a serialized field of type layerMask and assign the layer (Target in my case) you defined in the inspector:

```
// assign in the inspector
[SerializeField] private LayerMask toHit;

// your code
//..

// you can define the hit variable in the if statement if you
// don't need it somewhere else using the syntax I have used,
// otherwise remove the var keyword, the 100 is the maxDistance value,
// use any value you wish. toHit determines what physic engine selects 
// and what ingores.
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 100, toHit))
{
   Debug.Log($"hit: {hit.transform.name}");
   Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
}
```

([Unity Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html))